# Chat window keeps reloading on iPad

Tags: bug, chat, ios-app, page-load, comment-to-chat-migration

When I tap a chat link in a comment, the Safari panel keeps reloading.

- App Version: 1.4.0.243
- Device: iPad 2 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.1 (Build 13B143)

Comment: Do you have an example?  I'm unable to reproduce on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285068/core-data-mixing-lightweight-and-custom-migration#comment39737649_25416751

Comment: @BrianNickel  after updating the app, the bug still occurs. What example do you expect?

Comment: when I tap chat links, it doesn't keep reloading. Is it happening for every chat link for you or just specific ones? If you long press and select "open in Safari" does Safari do it to or just our pop up?

Comment: @BrianNickel Safari does it too. This's weird, because if I'm tagged directly in chat, and open it in the noti panel, not clicking the link in comment, then Safari loads properly. Can you ping me in chat so that I could check this again?